# Token pegged to the average return of ex top 10 cryptos

Tags: contract-development, contract-design

summer is coming up and I'm taking some of my vacation time to develop a crypto currency of my own. I'm looking to create a token that has a return pegged the average of for example the top 10 cryptocurrencies, first of all is this possible? And if how would go ahead coding a token like this?

Thank you in advance, and take care!

Answer (score 1):

It's possible and I think it already exists. However I would simply create a contract that wraps these 10 tokens minting a new "index token", you could even choose different quotes for token.
Then you can burn this token to get back the 10 tokens, with a possible return/loss.

If token get quote on a DEX then arbitrageurs should keep the price proportionate to the value of the underlying 10 tokens, however this requires sufficient liquidity and volume.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!, I'm relatively new to the space so forgive my lack of knowledge. So what the contract would do is basically buying the tokens and wrapping them in an "index token". Once the holder sells their position the contract sells the tokens that previously been wrapped in the contract and the possible return/loss gets passed on to the holder?

Comment: This isn't what I meant but could be anoter solution (more expensive in terms of gas) that doesn't require arbitrageurs.
I meant a contract that takes these 10 tokens in its balance and mint a new "index token", and similarly it takes this "index token" and free these 10 tokens.
Then if you quote this new "index token" on DeX people will start buying/selling and wrap/unwrap to make profit, and this will keep the price aligned with the underlying.

Comment: Great!, thank you for giving me things to further research!. Take care Andrea!